# How to write finite difference scheme of Poisson Equation with Periodic boundary and Neumann boundary?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am trying to write the numerical scheme of Poisson equation by using finite difference.

$\begin{equation*}
- \Delta u + \lambda u = f(x,y) ~~on ~~(0,1)~\times~(0,1)\\ 
\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} (x,0)=0=\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} (x,1)~~~x \in [0,1]\\ u(0,y)=u(1,y)~~~~~ ,~~~ y \in [0,1]
\end{equation*}$.

I used the five-point stencil for the computation of the internal nodes, and I define the new nodes for the computation of Neumann boundary. I removed these new nodes from the equation by using the central difference.

Now I am little confuse about how to handle the periodic boundary conditions on two sides of the square?

Can anyone please suggest some idea or notes, how to calculate the values of nodes in the two sides of the domain?

Comment: Why don't you tackle this periodic problem in Fourier space in closed form ?

Comment: @Pete I am learning finite difference method topic. I solved Poisson equation with DirichletBC and Neumann boundary condition. But I don't know how to solve the periodic one.

Comment: Since you work in a periodic setting, you can extend the grid periodically such that the point $(x_n,y)$ and $(x_0,y)$ correspond to each other. You can now add equations to your linear system to enforce that the value at $(x_n,y)$ and $(x_0,y)$ are equal.